# Create a HBITMAP which points to an existing memory buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, freeimage

I am using the [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net) library to store and manipulate bitmap data. Part of my code requires me to take a screenshot of a window (in Windows), and store it as a `FBITMAP*` (FreeImage's bitmap data structure). The method I have worked out of doing this involves two steps: capture the image, then convert it to a `FBITMAP*`.

To capture the image, I do something like this:

```
HWND window; // Assume this is a valid handle to my window
int width; // width of window client area
int height; // height of window client area

HDC windowDC = GetDC(window);
HDC captureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(windowDC);
HBITMAP screenshot = CreateCompatibleBitmap(windowDC, width, height);
SelectObject(captureDC, screenshot);
BitBlt(captureDC, 0, 0, width, height, 
       captureDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

ReleaseDC(window, windowDC);
DeleteDC(captureDC);
```

FreeImage provides a function which returns a raw pointer to the pixel data:

`BYTE* FreeImage_GetBits(FBITMAP*)`

[The FAQ](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/faq.html) explains that a `HBITMAP` (WinAPI handle to a bitmap) can be converted to a `FBITMAP*` using `GetDIBits`, which takes a source `HBITMAP` and a destination raw pointer as arguments, and copies the pixel data from one to the other.

The problem with this approach is that I have copied the data twice - once in the `BitBlt` from the window DC to the `HBITMAP` selected in the memory DC, and then again from the `HBITMAP` to the FreeImage memory buffer. I wish to remove this inefficiency and copy the data directly to my raw pointer in the `BitBlt` operation. For this to work, I need a memory DC which has a `HBITMAP` selected into it, and where that `HBITMAP` points to my memory buffer instead of to memory that Windows allocated for it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that you should select `screenshot` back out of `captureDC` before deleting `captureDC`.  You should also delete `screenshot` with `DeleteObject`.

Comment: You cannot create `HBITMAP` on top of existing memory block. You can, however, create a bitmap using `CreateDIBSection` and obtain a raw pointer into its underlying memory block for further `memcpy` copying. You might also want to look at `GetDIBits` for getting DC data into memory block.

Comment: CreateDibSection give you access to the memory buffer. Not easy to use at first. Here some sample that may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2841/How-to-replace-a-color-in-a-HBITMAP